# Android simulation fails to run dexer (Win 7)

Tags: java, android, ios, windows, titanium

I've inherited an Appcelerator Titanium project that's been known to successfully build for Android and iOS, but I had LOADS of problems getting it to run in Mac and Linux. I'm giving Windows a chance now, and I suspect the issue I'm having is somewhere within the Android SDK rather then Titanium. Here's my log:

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.2.3, Titanium SDK version 3.2.3.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
[INFO] :   Found Titanium plugin id=ti.alloy version=1.0 
[INFO] :   Deploy type: development
[INFO] :   Building for target: emulator
[INFO] :   Building for emulator: titanium_1_WVGA800
[INFO] :   Targeting Android SDK: 19
[INFO] :   Building for the following architectures: armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86
[INFO] :   Signing with keystore: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\dev_keystore (tidev)
[INFO] :   Debugging disabled
[INFO] :   Profiler disabled
[INFO] :   Forcing rebuild: C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\build-manifest.json does not exist
[INFO] :   Found Alloy app in C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\app
[INFO] :   Executing Alloy compile: alloy.cmd compile C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\app --config platform=android,version=0,simtype=none,devicefamily=none,deploytype=development
[INFO] :   ----- MVC GENERATION -----
[INFO] :   [global style] loading from cache...
[INFO] :   [index.xml] view processing...
[INFO] :     style:      "index.tss"
[INFO] :     view:       "index.xml"
[INFO] :     controller: "index.js"
[INFO] :     created:    "Resources\android\alloy\controllers\index.js"
[INFO] :     created:     "Resources\android\alloy\styles\index.js"
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   [app.js] using cached app.js...
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   ----- OPTIMIZING -----
[INFO] :   - android\alloy.js
[INFO] :   - android\alloy\sync\localStorage.js
[INFO] :   - android\alloy\sync\properties.js
[INFO] :   - android\alloy\sync\sql.js
[INFO] :   
[INFO] :   Alloy compiled in 0.47142s
[INFO] :   Alloy compiler completed successfully
[INFO] :   Launching emulator: titanium_1_WVGA800
[INFO] :   Running: C:\android-sdk-win\tools\emulator.exe "-avd" "titanium_1_WVGA800" "-port" "5554" "-no-boot-anim" "-partition-size" "128" "-sdcard" "C:\Users\vredchenko\.android\avd\titanium_1_WVGA800.avd\sdcard.img"
[INFO] :   Processing JavaScript files
[INFO] :   Writing C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\bin\assets\app.json
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-utils.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-geolocation.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-accelerometer.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-contacts.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-map.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-gesture.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-calendar.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.res.zip
[INFO] :   Extracting module resources: C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-database.res.zip
[INFO] :   No aidl files to compile, continuing
[INFO] :   Generating i18n files
[INFO] :   Generating C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\res\values\theme.xml
[INFO] :   Packaging application: C:\android-sdk-win\build-tools\19.0.3\aapt.exe "package" "-f" "-m" "-J" "C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\gen" "-M" "C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\AndroidManifest.xml" "-A" "C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\bin\assets" "-S" "C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\res" "-I" "C:\android-sdk-win\platforms\android-19\android.jar" "-I" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\titanium.jar" "-F" "C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\bin\app.ap_"
[INFO] :   Building Java source files: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\javac.exe "-J-Xmx256M" "-encoding" "utf8" "-bootclasspath" "C:\android-sdk-win\platforms\android-19\android.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\kroll-v8.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\thirdparty.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\kroll-common.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\titanium.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\android-support-v4.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-utils.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-geolocation.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-accelerometer.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-contacts.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-map.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-gesture.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-calendar.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-database.jar;C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\lib\titanium-verify.jar;ApplicationStylesheet.class;R.class;TestActivity.class;TestAppInfo.class;TestApplication.class" "-d" "C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\bin\classes" "-proc:none" "-target" "1.6" "-source" "1.6" "@C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\java-sources.txt"
[INFO] :   Running dexer: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java.exe "-Xmx1024M" "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit" "-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\android-sdk-win\platform-tools" "-jar" "C:\android-sdk-win\build-tools\19.0.3\lib\dx.jar" "--dex" "--output=C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\bin\classes.dex" "C:\Users\vredchenko\Documents\Titanium_Studio_Workspace\Test\build\android\bin\classes" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\lib\titanium-verify.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\kroll-v8.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-network.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\thirdparty.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-xml.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\jaxen-1.1.1.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-analytics.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-android.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\ti-commons-codec-1.3.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\kroll-common.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\titanium.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-app.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-ui.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\android-support-v4.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\nineoldandroids-appc-2.4.0.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-filesystem.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-media.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-locale.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-utils.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-geolocation.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-accelerometer.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-contacts.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-map.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-gesture.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-calendar.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-platform.jar" "C:\Users\vredchenko\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\3.2.3.GA\android\modules\titanium-database.jar"
[ERROR] :  Failed to run dexer:
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
```

Says it fails to run dexer.
Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I've tried to run the line just before the error: Running dexer: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java.exe "-Xmx1024M" manually - it was complaining about heap size so I reduced it to 512M and it worked, but I guess it does not do anything on it's own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lower Java Xmx setting to e.g. 512M To do this you need in command line execute this command:

**ti config android.dx.maxMemory 512M**

Answer (score 0):

If you ran the simulator several times and suddenly appears this error dont need to panic just try the above code.If it dose not work then just shut down the PC and start again open the Titanium and run the emulator.

It works for me :D